# Gnome Keyboard shortcut for Cut/Copy/Paste commands?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome

I do want to create a global command for Cut/Copy/Paste commands using the AddNewShortcut (+ button) from the bottom of the "Keyboard Shortcuts" of the Settings app of the Gnome shell, and I can't find the correct "Command" for this operations.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

There is no command to initiate copying. Not every single operation is performed by running a command in the first place.

The cut/copy/paste shortcuts are handled by each app itself – they are not a OS-wide feature. The OS itself **doesn't actually know** what you've selected and what you intend to copy, it only provides a way for apps to store/exchange the clipboard data and that's it.

(In theory it would be possible to have a system where apps could be sent abstract requests to "paste at cursor" or "copy selected"... but such a thing doesn't actually exist on Linux/X11 today.)

So if you wanted to create a new global shortcut that invokes e.g. 'Copy' then you'd need to use *xdotool* to actually [send a fake Ctrl+C keypress](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490686/how-do-i-make-xdotool-press-ctrl-c-and-ctrl-v) to the active window.

```
xdotool getactivewindow key ctrl+c
```